# Kubernetes v1.12 dashboard is running but timeout occurred while accessing it via api server proxy

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

Link: [Kubernetes v1.12 dashboard is running but timeout occurred while accessing it via api server proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569760/kubernetes-v1-12-dashboard-is-running-but-timeout-occurred-while-accessing-it-vi)
Started: 2018-12-01
Title: Kubernetes v1.12 dashboard is running but timeout occurred while accessing it via api server proxy

Body:
I have windows 10 home (1803 update) host machine, Virtual Box 5.22, 2 guest ubuntu 18.04.1 servers.
Each guest has 2 networks: NAT (host IP 10.0.2.15) and shared host-only with gateway IP 192.168.151.1. 
I set IPs:

1. for k8s master(ubuk8sma) - 192.168.151.21
2. for worker1 (ubuk8swrk1) - 192.168.151.22

I remained docker as is, version is 18.09.0.
I installed k8s version stable-1.12 on master and worker. For master init is:

```
K8S_POD_CIDR='10.244.0.0/16'
K8S_IP_ADDR='192.168.151.21'
K8S_VER='stable-1.12' # or latest
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=${K8S_POD_CIDR} --apiserver-advertise-address=${K8S_IP_ADDR} --kubernetes-version ${K8S_VER} --ignore-preflight-errors=all
```

Why I set "ignore errors" flag:

[ERROR SystemVerification]: unsupported docker version: 18.09.0

I was reluctant to reinstall k8s fully compatible docker version (may be not very smart move, just I'm usually eager to try the latest stuff).

For CNI I installed flannel network:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
```

After installing worker1 nodes state looks like:

```
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ kubectl get nodes

NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
ubuk8sma     Ready    master   6d     v1.12.2
ubuk8swrk1   Ready    <none>   4d1h   v1.12.2
```

No big issues shown up. Next I wanted is to have visualization of this pretty k8s bundle ecosystem, so I headed towards installing k8s dashboard.
I followed "defaults" path, with zero intervention, if possible. I used this yaml:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

From basic level it looks like installed, deployed to worker Pod, running. From pod list info:

```
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ kubectl get all --namespace=kube-system

NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/coredns-576cbf47c7-4tzm9                1/1     Running   5          6d
pod/coredns-576cbf47c7-tqtpw                1/1     Running   5          6d
pod/etcd-ubuk8sma                           1/1     Running   7          6d
pod/kube-apiserver-ubuk8sma                 1/1     Running   7          6d
pod/kube-controller-manager-ubuk8sma        1/1     Running   11         6d
pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-rt442             1/1     Running   3          4d1h
pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-zx78x             1/1     Running   5          6d
pod/kube-proxy-6b6mc                        1/1     Running   6          6d
pod/kube-proxy-zcchn                        1/1     Running   3          4d1h
pod/kube-scheduler-ubuk8sma                 1/1     Running   10         6d
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b   1/1     Running   1          2d1h

NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   6d
service/kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.103.36.134   <none>        443/TCP         2d1h

NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                     AGE
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64     2         2         2       2            2           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64     6d
...
daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                2         2         2       2            2           <none>                            6d

NAME                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/coredns                2         2         2            2           6d
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard   1         1         1            1           2d1h

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/coredns-576cbf47c7                2         2         2       6d
replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978   1         1         1       2d1h
```

I started proxy for both API server and dashboard service validation:
kubectl proxy

Version check for API server:

```
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ curl http://localhost:8001/version
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "12",
  "gitVersion": "v1.12.2",
  "gitCommit": "17c77c7898218073f14c8d573582e8d2313dc740",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2018-10-24T06:43:59Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.10.4",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}
```

And here is problem I'm writing this question about:

```
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ curl "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/"
Error: 'dial tcp 10.244.1.8:8443: i/o timeout'
Trying to reach: 'https://10.244.1.8:8443/'
```

Fragment of Pod info:

```
status:   
  conditions:   
  - lastProbeTime: null   
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-11-29T07:16:04Z   
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-11-30T06:53:24Z
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-11-30T06:53:24Z
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-11-29T07:16:04Z
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://fb0937959c7680046130e670c483877e4c0f1854870cb0b20ed4fe066d72df18
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.0
    imageID: docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64@sha256:1d2e1229a918f4bc38b5a3f9f5f11302b3e71f8397b492afac7f273a0008776a
    lastState:
      terminated:
        containerID: docker://f85e1cc50f59adbd8a13d42694aef7c5e726c07b3d852a26288c4bfc1124c718
        exitCode: 2
        finishedAt: 2018-11-30T06:53:21Z
        reason: Error
        startedAt: 2018-11-29T07:16:07Z
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    ready: true
    restartCount: 1
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: 2018-11-30T06:53:23Z
  hostIP: 10.0.2.15
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.244.1.8
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: 2018-11-29T07:16:04Z
```

Docker check on worker1 node:

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE                   COMMAND                                                                                            CREATED             STATUS                   NAMES
fb0937959c...   sha256:0dab2435c100...  "/dashboard --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0 --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --auto-generate-certificates"   27 hours ago        Up 27 hours              k8s_kubernetes-dashboard_kube...
```

Tried to check Pod logs, no luck:

```
DASHBOARD_POD_NAME='kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b'
kubectl -n kube-system logs $DASHBOARD_POD_NAME
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource ( pods/log kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b)
```

Tried to wget from API server:

```
API_SRV_POD_NAME='kube-apiserver-ubuk8sma'
kubectl  -n 'kube-system' exec -ti $API_SRV_POD_NAME wget https://10.244.1.8:8443/
```

No response.

Tried to check dashboard service existence, no luck:

```
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ kubectl get svc $DASHBOARD_SVC_NAME
Error from server (NotFound): services "kubernetes-dashboard" not found
```

Checked IP route table on API server:

```
kubectl  -n 'kube-system' exec -ti $API_SRV_POD_NAME ip route show
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 scope link  src 10.0.2.15
10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100
10.244.0.0/24 dev cni0 scope link  src 10.244.0.1
10.244.1.0/24 via 10.244.1.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link  src 172.17.0.1
192.168.151.0/24 dev enp0s8 scope link  src 192.168.151.21
```

For reference, enp0s3 is NAT NIC adapter, enp0s8 - host-only one. 
I see flannel route 10.244.1.x. Seems to be the issue is hardly about network misconfig (but I can be wrong).
So, dashboard Pod looks like running, but has some errors and I cannot diagnose which ones. Could you help to find root cause and ideally make dashboard service run without errors? 
Thanks in advance, folks!

Update1:

I see events on master:

```
  Type     Reason                  Age                From                 Message
  ----     ------                  ----               ----                 -------
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  11h                kubelet, ubuk8swrk1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "43191144d447d0e9da52c8b6600bd96a23fab1e96c79af8c8fedc4e4e50882c7" network for pod "kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b_kube-system" network: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Normal   SandboxChanged          11h (x4 over 11h)  kubelet, ubuk8swrk1  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulled                  11h                kubelet, ubuk8swrk1  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                 11h                kubelet, ubuk8swrk1  Created container
  Normal   Started                 11h                kubelet, ubuk8swrk1  Started container
```

Error about subnet.env absence - a bit strange, as both master and minion have it (well, maybe created on the fly):

```
u1@ubuk8swrk1:~$ ls -la /run/flannel/subnet.env
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 96 Dec  3 08:15 /run/flannel/subnet.env
```

This is dashboard service descriptor:

```
Name:                   kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:              kube-system
Labels:                 k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
  Service Account:  kubernetes-dashboard
  Containers:
   kubernetes-dashboard:
    Image:      k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.0
    Port:       8443/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Args:
      --auto-generate-certificates
    Liveness:     http-get https://:8443/ delay=30s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /certs from kubernetes-dashboard-certs (rw)
      /tmp from tmp-volume (rw)
  Volumes:
   kubernetes-dashboard-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  kubernetes-dashboard-certs
    Optional:    false
   tmp-volume:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

This is reduced description of pods(original yaml is 35K, too much to share):

```
Name:               coredns-576cbf47c7-4tzm9
Namespace:          kube-system
Node:               ubuk8sma/10.0.2.15
Labels:             k8s-app=kube-dns
                    pod-template-hash=576cbf47c7
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.244.0.14
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/coredns-576cbf47c7
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  docker://0efcd043407d93fb9d052045828489f6b99bb59b4f0882ec89e1897071609b77
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.2
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  6
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Events:          <none>

Name:               etcd-ubuk8sma
Namespace:          kube-system
Priority:           2000000000
PriorityClassName:  system-cluster-critical
Node:               ubuk8sma/10.0.2.15
Labels:             component=etcd
                    tier=control-plane
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.0.2.15
Containers:
  etcd:
    Container ID:  docker://ba2bdcf5fa558beabdd8578628d71480d595d5ee3bb5c4edf42407419010144b
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.2.24
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/etcd@sha256:905d7ca17fd02bc24c0eba9a062753aba15db3e31422390bc3238eb762339b20
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      etcd
      --advertise-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379
      --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt
      --client-cert-auth=true
      --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
      --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2380
      --initial-cluster=ubuk8sma=https://127.0.0.1:2380
      --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
      --listen-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379
      --listen-peer-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2380
      --name=ubuk8sma
      --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt
      --peer-client-cert-auth=true
      --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key
      --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
      --snapshot-count=10000
      --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 03 Dec 2018 08:12:56 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Wed, 28 Nov 2018 09:31:46 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 03 Dec 2018 08:12:35 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  8
    Liveness:       exec [/bin/sh -ec ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://[127.0.0.1]:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key get foo] delay=15s timeout=15s period=10s #success=1 #failure=8
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd from etcd-certs (rw)
      /var/lib/etcd from etcd-data (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Events:            <none>


Name:               kube-apiserver-ubuk8sma
Namespace:          kube-system
Node:               ubuk8sma/10.0.2.15
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.0.2.15
Containers:
  kube-apiserver:
    Container ID:  docker://099b2a30772b969c3919b57fd377980673f03a820afba6034daa70f011271a52
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.12.2
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver@sha256:094929baf3a7681945d83a7654b3248e586b20506e28526121f50eb359cee44f
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      kube-apiserver
      --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
      --advertise-address=192.168.151.21
      --allow-privileged=true
      --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
      --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
      --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
      --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
      --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
      --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
      --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
      --insecure-port=0
      --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
      --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
      --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
      --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
      --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
      --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
      --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
      --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
      --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
      --secure-port=6443
      --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
      --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
      --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
      --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 03 Dec 2018 08:13:00 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  8
    Liveness:     http-get https://192.168.151.21:6443/healthz delay=15s timeout=15s period=10s #success=1 #failure=8
    Environment:  <none>
Events:            <none>

Name:               kube-flannel-ds-amd64-rt442
Namespace:          kube-system
Node:               ubuk8swrk1/10.0.2.15
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.0.2.15
Controlled By:      DaemonSet/kube-flannel-ds-amd64
Init Containers:
  install-cni:
    Container ID:  docker://a6377b0fe1b040235c24e9ca19455c56e77daecf688b212cfea5553b6e59ff68
    Image:         quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-amd64
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  4
Containers:
  kube-flannel:
    Container ID:  docker://f7029bc2144c1ab8654407d742c1079df0059d418b7ba86b886091b5ad8c34a3
    Image:         quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-amd64
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /opt/bin/flanneld
    Args:
      --ip-masq
      --kube-subnet-mgr
    State:          Running
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  4
Events:          <none>

Name:               kube-proxy-6b6mc
Namespace:          kube-system
Node:               ubuk8sma/10.0.2.15
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.0.2.15
```

The biggest suspect is node IP. I see 10.0.2.15 (NAT IP) everywhere. But host-only NIC should be used. I had long story of setting up network properly for my ubuntu VMs. 
I edited `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` before k8s setup (thanks https://askubuntu.com/questions/984445/netplan-configuration-on-ubuntu-17-04-virtual-machine?rq=1 for help). Example for master config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 10.0.2.2
        metric: 0
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.151.21/24]
      routes:
      - to: 192.168.151.1/24
        via: 192.168.151.1
        metric: 100
```

Only after this and a few more changes NAT and host-only networks start work together. NAT remains default net adapter. Likely that's why its IP is everywhere. For api server I set `--advertise-address=192.168.151.21` explicitly. That reduced using NAT IP at least for it.
So, maybe root cause is different, but current question, how to reconfigure networks to replace NAT IP to host-only. I already tried this for  `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`

```
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip=192.168.151.21"
```

Restarted kubelet:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

Didn't help. Restarted VMs. Didn't help (I only expected kubelet related changes, but nothing changed). Explored a few configs (5+) for potential changes, no luck.

Update2:

I mentioned NAT address config issue above. I resolved it with editing `/etc/default/kubelet` config. I found that idea in comments for this article:
https://medium.com/@joatmon08/playing-with-kubeadm-in-vagrant-machines-part-2-bac431095706

Dashboard config part now has proper IP:

```
hostIP: 192.168.151.22
phase: Running
podIP: 10.244.1.13
```

Then I went to docker container for API and tried to reach podIP via wget,ping,traceroute. Timeouts everywhere. Routes:

```
/ # route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.244.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cni0
10.244.1.0      10.244.1.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.151.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s8
```

Attempt to perform curl call from master VM:

```
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ curl -v -i -kSs "https://192.168.151.21:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/" -H "$K8S_AUTH_HEADER"
...
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x565072b5a750)
> GET /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ HTTP/2
> Host: 192.168.151.21:6443
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1.....
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 503
HTTP/2 503
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 92
content-length: 92
< date: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 08:44:25 GMT
date: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 08:44:25 GMT

<
Error: 'dial tcp 10.244.1.13:8443: i/o timeout'
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.151.21 left intact
Trying to reach: 'https://10.244.1.13:8443/'
```

Service info for dashboard:

```
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.103.36.134   <none>        443/TCP   5d
```

A bit more details:

```
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ kubectl -n kube-system describe services kubernetes-dashboard
Name:              kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:         kube-system
Labels:            k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.103.36.134
Port:              <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:        8443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.13:8443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Also I tried to go to shell, both via kubectl and docker. For any usual linux command I see this 'OCI runtime exec failed' issue:

```
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ DASHBOARD_POD_NAME='kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b'
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ kubectl -v=9 -n kube-system exec "$DASHBOARD_POD_NAME" -- env
I1204 09:57:17.673345   23517 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/u1/.kube/config
I1204 09:57:17.679526   23517 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.12.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/17c77c7" 'https://192.168.151.21:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b'
I1204 09:57:17.703924   23517 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://192.168.151.21:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b 200 OK in 23 milliseconds
I1204 09:57:17.703957   23517 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I1204 09:57:17.703971   23517 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Length: 3435
I1204 09:57:17.703984   23517 round_trippers.go:414]     Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 09:57:17 GMT
I1204 09:57:17.703997   23517 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Type: application/json
I1204 09:57:17.704866   23517 request.go:942] Response Body: {"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b","generateName":"kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b","uid":"a1d005b8-f3a6-11e8-a2d0-08002783a80f"...
I1204 09:57:17.740811   23517 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XPOST  -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v4.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v3.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v2.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: channel.k8s.io" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.12.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/17c77c7" 'https://192.168.151.21:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b/exec?command=env&container=kubernetes-dashboard&container=kubernetes-dashboard&stderr=true&stdout=true'
I1204 09:57:17.805528   23517 round_trippers.go:405] POST https://192.168.151.21:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-crl7b/exec?command=env&container=kubernetes-dashboard&container=kubernetes-dashboard&stderr=true&stdout=true 101 Switching Protocols in 64 milliseconds
I1204 09:57:17.805565   23517 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I1204 09:57:17.805581   23517 round_trippers.go:414]     Connection: Upgrade
I1204 09:57:17.805594   23517 round_trippers.go:414]     Upgrade: SPDY/3.1
I1204 09:57:17.805607   23517 round_trippers.go:414]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v4.channel.k8s.io
I1204 09:57:17.805620   23517 round_trippers.go:414]     Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 09:57:17 GMT
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"env\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
F1204 09:57:18.088488   23517 helpers.go:119] command terminated with exit code 126
```

So, I cannot reach pod, cannot go to shell there. But at least I see some logs:

```
u1@ubuk8sma:~$ kubectl -n kube-system logs -p $DASHBOARD_POD_NAME
2018/12/03 08:15:16 Starting overwatch
2018/12/03 08:15:16 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2018/12/03 08:15:16 Using service account token for csrf signing
2018/12/03 08:15:16 No request provided. Skipping authorization
2018/12/03 08:15:16 Successful initial request to the apiserver, version: v1.12.2
2018/12/03 08:15:16 Generating JWE encryption key
2018/12/03 08:15:16 New synchronizer has been registered: kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system. Starting
2018/12/03 08:15:16 Starting secret synchronizer for kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder in namespace kube-system
2018/12/03 08:15:18 Initializing JWE encryption key from synchronized object
2018/12/03 08:15:18 Creating in-cluster Heapster client
2018/12/03 08:15:19 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2018/12/03 08:15:19 Auto-generating certificates
2018/12/03 08:15:19 Successfully created certificates
2018/12/03 08:15:19 Serving securely on HTTPS port: 8443
2018/12/03 08:15:49 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
```

No ideas, where to go further for now to fix this timeout.

Comment: Can you describe dashboard Pod information: `kubectl describe pod $DASHBOARD_POD_NAME -n kube-system` or even check dashboard deployment: `kubectl describe deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system` ?

Comment: Hi @mk_sta, I added pods and dashboard service info (not in full details, as desc-n for pods are too big). I made some progress on nodeIP side. But it didn't help in resolving timeout.

Comment: Check this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/) for general troubleshooting actions in `kubeadm` k8s cluster, maybe be it will be helpful for you to find a root cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, @mk_sta. I gave up with 1.12 k8s, moving towards 1.13, will update if have the same issue.